# Asp.Net Users, Roles and OAuth2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I'm working on a WebAPI which will have users with different profiles.

There's some stuff relevant to the WebAPI in relation to users which should be stored there not including login or other identifying information.

In addition to being able to sign up to the WebAPI users database users can alternatively use an OAuth2 provider to be identified and be entered into the database.

So my question is, should the users information be stored in the WebAPI? how should I distinguish between users who directly signed up through the webapi or used a seperate OAuth2 provider (such as Facebook)?

I was thinking of making a separate authentication server the WebAPI will use for users who register directly then we can use OAuth2 the same way for both userse who signed up directly to use the WebAPI and those who used a different OAuth2 service.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Depending on your application, you will probably want to implement a separate auth mechanism completely from other providers. Unless you don't intend on having any authorization roles for your application, then the other auth providers should only be used for authentication and integration with said provider. I would have an authentication route for each provider and one for just vanilla login that once authenticated would all hit the same identity lookup and return an authorization token that I manage.

Comment: I've decided to use Asp.Net identity stuff for the users for now, when I add OAuth2 support for other providers I'll simply create the users through the same workflow without a password requirement and simply add a field to the database to check for the correct OAuth2 provider.

Hopefully that makes sense to you because I'm not talking from a place of experience :)